# Is this Google proxy a fake crawler: google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com?

Tags: proxy, google, web-crawlers

Recently I discover that some variants of a google proxy visits my sites. I doubt these are legal Google crawlers because these crawlers are NOT always behind a proxy (like the hostname describes) and identify itself as a browser. The hostname is formatted similar/like Googlebot but with the string 'proxy' added to it.

My PHP blocking class blocks these crawlers, but is it correct to block these ones? What are they and are these from google or is it fake?

Here some info about one of these crawlers:

```
BlockedIp Notifier Report - IP:66.249.81.131:: has been blocked

Ticket ID : {EVNT_136877_2013040520130402_33147_10348}  
Event type : Access blocked  
Event date : 04/05/2013 - 19:17:47 (server date-time)  
Event counter : First occurring  
Processed url : http://streambutler.net/  
From url : http://www.google.com/search  
Domain : streambutler.net 
Domain IP : 95.170.70.213  
Visitor IP : 66.249.81.131  
Proxy IP : 66.249.81.131  

Critical : Yes  
Action required : No  


Additional information
Problem : Bad Proxy - via 66.249.81.131 
Hostname : google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com 
Block : Yes 
Refferer : http://www.google.com/search 
AgentString : Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like G... 
Browser : Chrome 22.0.1229 
Platform : Linux 
Robot : No 
Mobile : No 
Tablet : No 
Console : No 
Crawler : No 
Agent_type : browser 
Agent_name : chrome 
Agent_version : 22.0.1229 
Os_type : linux 
Os_name : linux 
Agent_languagetag : en 
Status : ok 
Request : 66.249.81.131 
Languagecode : us 
Country : United States 
Region : California 
City : Mountain View 
Zipcode : 94043 
Latitude : 37.406 
Longitude : -122.079 
Timezone : -07:00 

Available from  : \'http 
Areacode : 0 
Dmacode : 0 
Continentcode : na 
Currencycode : USD 
Currencysymbol : &#36; 
Currencysymbol_utf8 : $ 
Currencyconverter : 1 
Extended : 1 
Organization : NULL
```

**other variants found**

- `google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com` (identifies itself as Firefox
  6.0?)
- `google-proxy-66-249-81-148.google.com` (tries to access a javascript file)
- `google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com`
- `google-proxy-66-249-81-111.google.com` (tries to access a javascript
  file)
- `google-proxy-66-249-81-164.google.com`

The first one in the list is a weird one, Firefox 6.0 on Windows 7 and same IP as example above but is not a proxy in the next log? If it is mobile proxy, this is very weird or not?

```
Ticket ID : {EVNT_164838_2013040520130402_33147_10348}  
Event type : Access blocked  
Event date : 04/05/2013 - 19:19:07 (server date-time)  
Event counter : First occurring  
Processed url : http://streambutler.net/  
From url : Unknown or direct link  
Domain : streambutler.net 
Domain IP : 95.170.70.213  
Visitor IP : 66.249.81.131  
Proxy IP : (not present)  

Critical : Yes  
Action required : No  


Additional information
Problem : Blocked Server IP address (analysis) - 66.249.81.131 
Hostname : google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com 
Block : Yes 
Refferer : (direct access) 
AgentString : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0 ... 
Browser : Firefox 6.0 
Platform : Windows 7 
Robot : No 
Mobile : No 
Tablet : No 
Console : No 
Crawler : No 
Agent_type : browser 
Agent_name : firefox 
Agent_version : 6.0 
Os_type : windows 
Os_name : windows 7 
Agent_languagetag : en 
Status : ok 
Request : 66.249.81.131 
Languagecode : us 
Country : United States 
Region : California 
City : Mountain View 
Zipcode : 94043 
Latitude : 37.406 
Longitude : -122.079 
Timezone : -07:00 
Available from  : \'http 
Areacode : 0 
Dmacode : 0 
Continentcode : na 
Currencycode : USD 
Currencysymbol : &#36; 
Currencysymbol_utf8 : $ 
Currencyconverter : 1 
Extended : 1 
Organization : NULL
```

Anyone has info about these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got it!** These 'crawlers' are not crawlers but are part of the live website preview used in the Google search engine.

I have tried this, to show one of my websites in the preview and yes, there it is, received a blockedIP message.

If you want users to be able to view a preview of your website, you have to accept these 'crawlers'.

Like others said: "the root domain of that URL is `google.com` and that can't be easily spoofed".

**Conclusion:** You can trust these bot's or crawlers and it is used to show a preview in Google search.

Comment: Google discontinued page previews and i just got hit with ~10 different google proxy ips in various areas of the site.

Answer (score 5):

I have also found that google proxy accessed my website several times (30+) in the very same second:

```
66.249.81.106 - - [30/Aug/2013:01:26:35 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 280329
66.249.81.106 - - [30/Aug/2013:01:26:35 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 280329
66.249.81.106 - - [30/Aug/2013:01:26:35 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 280329
66.249.81.106 - - [30/Aug/2013:01:26:35 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 280329
```

...

and rising my server loads. This was strange because in robots.txt I set:

```
Crawl-delay: 1
```

(crawler (google) should access the site at a maximum frequency of 1 queries per second (cca), Google does NOT ignore this setting).

So I tried to create a PHP script to block google(any) IPs if IP does it for more than 30 seconds, but I discovered **something different**. With this code, i was searching for the visitor IP address:

```
function get_visitor_ip_address($server)
{
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key)
    {
        //if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true)
        if ($server->testIp($key))
        {
            //foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip)
            foreach (explode(',', $server->getEscaped($key)) as $ip)
            {
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false) return $ip;
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false) return $ip;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this code returned different IP address (usually Middle east, Africa, or similar locations, ie. 197.132.255.244). This is from my PHP logs

```
IP address 197.132.255.244 banned at 2013-08-30 01:26:35 for the 1. time exceeding 30 visits in a second, banned for 30 minutes
```

**Interestedly, my Apache server stored Google proxy IP address to my access logs, not the 197.132.255.244). See the apache logs at the beginning, same date & time, etc... tested several times**

>
>
>

While my PHP script searches for the IP address in several ways, notice the different server params in the PHP code:

```
'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR'
```

and this finds and logs the "correct" IP address - 197.132.255.244 (tested several times with various attackers)

```
http://whois.domaintools.com/197.132.255.244
```

>
>
>

**My conclusion:**

I think, some people are using Google services (like Google translate, Google mobile, etc.) for accessing (blocked) websites (in schools etc.) but also for DOS attacks and similar activity. How?

This way:

```
http://www.gmodules.com/ig/proxy?url=http://www.yoursite.com
http://www.google.com/translate?langpair=de|en&u=www.yoursite.com
```

(change to your website instead of www.yoursite.com)

or other ways:

```
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1322/use_google_proxy_bypass_blocked_site/
```

I think, it's up to you if you find and block the original IP address (197.132.255.244) with the help of this PHP function, which works even when the attacker is using a Google Proxy, and you will display them short message "you have exceeded our limits" or empty/error page, as I do...

or you block the Google Proxy IP (66.249.81.106 or similar), for example directly in the .httaccess file, if proxy exceeds your allowed limits. You will not block the Google crawler with this, but you may disable the functionality, when someone real (not attacker) wants to translate your webpage etc.

Comment: very good analysis of the problem, i couldnt proove it but i was sure it was this kind of problem, google being used like some kind of proxy, for different reasons, by google employees or not.

Comment: Interesting analisys

Answer (score 3):

These are not fake and are used, these are private proxies used by staff members for various manual tasks/audits/reviews and should not be blocked...

Comment: Thanks for the info but do you have a source of that?

Comment: no, but it's obvious as the ip resolves to `google.com` which is not spoofed.

Comment: Al right, understand that faking IP and other things is not useful when they want replies to the request like a DOS attack. But if it is from google itself, isn't it a bit strange that Firefox 6.0 useragent is used (also old version when used on PC) or is Firefox Fennic but running on Windows 7? Strange right? Sometimes it is not a proxy sometimes a proxy from same IP and the requests follow up in a second or less. Sometimes Firefox useragent and sometimes Chrome. That's makes me wonder if it is fake.

Comment: A DOS attack is completely different than a bot/someone visiting your website.

Comment: I know that a DOS attack is something different than visit a site. That's not the point.

Comment: "no, but it's obvious as the ip resolves to google.com which is not spoofed" One needs to do both the reverse and forward DNS query and check they match because otherwise anyone can insert any PTR record for IP addresses it controls pointing to any name of it wishes, including those it does not control. This is exactly what Google recommends at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en (they do not provide public list of IP addresses)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience as @James and @FFrewin; when testing a new "secret" app/URL I suddenly saw a bunch of traffic from various Google proxies. After some experimentation, it appears that (at least) Chrome on Android uses the these servers as part of their "Data Saver" functionality. The description says: "When Data Saver is turned On, Chrome uses Google servers to speed up and compress page loads". When I turned Data Saver off, the proxy traffic went away.

So these proxies aren't (or at least aren't completely) nefarious. Blocking them might alter or interfere with mobile users' ability to reach your site.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that some scrapers also use google proxy to get around detection or blocking.  I operate a retail site and am always battling to prevent price scrapers.  I have noticed that I get continuous visits to a stream of pages from the same google proxy even when blocked. Seems more like a bot that human user. I monitor my traffic and use various methods to identify scrapers and block them and this looks like another attempt to get around the existing blocks to scrape my content.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to provide links to Google docs on this subject.

These are Googlebots but [there are many different types of bots](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/overview-google-crawlers). Several explicitly ignore the robots.txt when its user initiated (such as Read Aloud for text-to-speech reading your site for the visually impaired). Others are just getting your favicon for favorites/bookmarks and need a logo, they ignore robots.txt because they are a bot but don't crawl your site.

To verify its a Google bot, [verify using a reverse DNS lookup](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/verifying-googlebot).

Example 1:

```
> host 66.249.66.1
1.66.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com.

> host crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com
crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com has address 66.249.66.1
```

Example 2:

```
> host 66.249.90.77
77.90.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer rate-limited-proxy-66-249-90-77.google.com.

> host rate-limited-proxy-66-249-90-77.google.com
rate-limited-proxy-66-249-90-77.google.com has address 66.249.90.77
```

Answer (score 1):

I came upon this thread while researching a handful of unusual log entries.  They are logged as google proxy in the same fashion as the posted question.  But the referer in the IIS log states google.com/search and included a UserAgent which looks real.  However, if this was a real crawler they would not need to imitate an Agent.

BUT the clincher is that this site is not live and is not on google's search yet.  In fact I had suspected I downloaded a virus a day or two ago, and I must have hand typed this complete address while testing the site.  So here is someone using a keystroke tracker and trying to follow up on all of my activity, but it looks like they are trying to hide behind the google search proxy?  I like the hypothesis about the 197 address.

The stem:/monitor/getAccount is simply a task endpoint which I hit occasionally to verify a new code build for testing.  No user or Google would ever find this:

```
    2018-03-09 06:56:29 10.138.0.4 GET /monitor/getAccount - 80 - 66.249.80.26 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+x86_64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko;+Google+Web+Preview)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 - http://www.google.com/search app.tru-stats.com 200 0 1236 0 426 31203
```

Comment: this is similar to my answer - I came for the same reasons here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue with UserAgent and the reason why it is most likely a legitimate crawler:

Web servers can be configured to respond to any of the headers in the web page requests including the UserAgent. If Google webbots all looked the same then I could have a shady website that makes itself look like an encyclopedia of useful information to webbots while delivering complete crap to general users with various other UserAgents with the goal being to score high on all sorts of Google searches. I'm pretty sure Google is smarter than that. They will use all sorts of bots with all sorts of UserAgents to verify content. Google can also use information gleaned from scans of that sort to detect smart sites that will flavour their content for different browsers in useful ways.

After all, the root domain of that URL is google.com and that can't be easily spoofed.

Also, accessing javascript files is completely normal for a Google webbot. It's looking for more URLs in the javascript. You can prevent google from scanning your scripts by using `<script rel="nofollow" src="code.js"></script>`.

Comment: Thank you for your information. See my answer. Some comment: The problem with 'rel="nofollow"' is that it is not w3c. I use another approach, when it is a bot, don't serve javascript files and sometimes don't serve CSS files.

Comment: a "legitimate crawler" like googlebot will respect the crawl delay and wont kill the server, this one is not respecting any crawl delay.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I also received a DOS attack from google-proxy:

> host 66.249.82.43
>   43.82.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer google-proxy-66-249-82-43.google.com.

log extracts:

```
Jun  9 21:19:43 gemelos kernel: PAX: From 66.249.82.43: execution attempt in: (null), 00000000-00000000 00000000
Jun  9 21:19:43 gemelos kernel: PAX: terminating task: /usr/sbin/apache2(apache2):25541, uid/euid: 81/81, PC: 00795f72, SP: b01666ec
Jun  9 21:19:43 gemelos kernel: PAX: bytes at PC: ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??
Jun  9 21:19:43 gemelos kernel: PAX: bytes at SP-4: a2be3e6c a262fa66 1d620670 00000000 0000000c a3315e34 00000005 1d9ba84c a2be3e6c a2614bb8 1d9baadc 00000003 00010006 a2b222c7 a3316880 a12977a8 1d9baaf0 36183700 1d9ba84c a31a7d26 a1939349
Jun  9 21:19:43 gemelos kernel: grsec: From 66.249.82.43: bruteforce prevention initiated for the next 30 minutes or until service restarted, stalling each fork 30 seconds.  Please investigate the crash report for /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:25541] uid/euid:81/81 gid/egid:81/81, parent /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:29657] uid/euid:0/0 gid/egid:0/0
Jun 10 00:03:40 gemelos kernel: grsec: denied resource overstep by requesting 18 for RLIMIT_NICE against limit 0 for /usr/bin/namecoind[namecoind:27085] uid/euid:105/105 gid/egid:122/122, parent /sbin/init[init:1] uid/euid:0/0 gid/egid:0/0
Jun 10 03:58:05 gemelos kernel: PAX: From 66.249.82.43: execution attempt in: <anonymous mapping>, 00000000-0001f000 00000000
Jun 10 03:58:05 gemelos kernel: PAX: terminating task: /usr/sbin/apache2(apache2):27985, uid/euid: 81/81, PC:    (nil), SP: b01666ec
Jun 10 03:58:05 gemelos kernel: PAX: bytes at PC: ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??
Jun 10 03:58:05 gemelos kernel: PAX: bytes at SP-4: 1d746620 a262fa66 1d6f34c0 00000000 0000000c a3315e34 00000005 1d7bb4dc a2be3e6c a2614bb8 1d7bb76c 00000003 00010006 a2b222c7 a3316880 a07a23c8 1d7bb780 36183700 1d7bb4dc a31a7d26 a1939349
Jun 10 03:58:05 gemelos kernel: grsec: From 66.249.82.43: bruteforce prevention initiated for the next 30 minutes or until service restarted, stalling each fork 30 seconds.  Please investigate the crash report for /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:27985] uid/euid:81/81 gid/egid:81/81, parent /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:29657] uid/euid:0/0 gid/egid:0/0
```

Comment: That is not a DOS attack. That is your web server crashing, probably due to a bug in your application.

Comment: sure ;) what I think is that google bot is rate limited, but not the tools they use from this google-proxy are NOT ( and those are just extracts of the DOS from this very IP.)

Answer (score 0):

When your servers are getting hit by bots, always Google their IP address before blocking them.

A search for "IP address 66.249.81.131" shows that this is an IP is that is owned by Google.

When a search for an IP address doesn't return a company that you want crawling your site, it's most likely safe to block it.

Answer (score 0):

I reached here after finding logs in my Web Application Firewall coming from `rate-limited-proxy-66-249-90-176.google.com`.

What make me suspicious about these logs is that they occurred under very special conditions. I was testing a secret URL on my web application to see how it the Firewall will respond. That was the first those secret URLs have been used and there was no way for anyone to know them. The firewall logged my calls to those URLs alongside with my IP as expected - but then after about 30seconds I saw some extra logs entries to the same secret URLs but this time from another IP - yet unknown to me.

I thought how is this possible, as it's only me that could have tried those URLs - then I did an IP look-up and it came out the above host: `rate-limited-proxy-66-249-90-176.google.com`.

Then I thought that this might be happening because I use Google's DNS to connect to the internet - and I didn't like the idea at all that Google would followed and tried out URLs that I type on my browser - so I changed my connection's DNS settings to use my local ISP's ones and tried again. But still when I tried a new secret URL, after 20-30 seconds I found another second call from that same Google's IPs.

Finally I enabled a VPN connection and re-tried with new secret URLs. This time  only my requests were the ones to reach my Web Application - not Google proxy followed me.

Conclusions are yours...